# Replace specific characters in line, c++

Tags: c++, replace, char, character

I am working on a program to decrypt text with a certain key. I'm trying to use `replace()` but it doesn't seem to be working. For example, `qwert` should decrypt to `hello`, but the output is `hlllo`; in this case the `w` in `qwert` gets decrypted to `e` but then re-decrypted to `l`.

input:

```
 xnm ceuob lrtzv ita hegfd tsmr xnm ypwq ktj
 should come out as:
 the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
 I'm getting:
 oga yaacd brozn aox gamav ovar oga lazy dog
```

How can I fix this?

```
int main()
{
    // ...
    myFile.open("decrypt.txt");
    while (myFile.good()) 
    {
        getline(myFile, line2);
        // now line2 is, e.g., "xnm ceuob lrtzv ita hegfd tsmr xnm ypwq ktj"

        // help here
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
        {
            replace(line2.begin(), line2.end(), key[i], fox[i]);
        }
        v.push_back(line2);
    }

    myFile.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < numline; i++) 
    {
        cout << "line " << i <<" = " << v[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok i removed all unecessary code and explained a little bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decrypt each character once. Instead of having two arrays, `key` and `fox`, which (apparently) contain characters to substitute, you might consider building a [map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) between input characters and their decrypted versions. Then you can simply walk over the input string, decrypting a character at a time.

```
std::map<char, char> lookup; 
// populate lookup such that lookup['q'] = 'h', lookup['w'] = 'e', etc.

// walk over line2, decrypting a character at a time.
for (int i = 0; i < line2.length(); i++)
{
    char c = line2[i];
    char d = lookup[c];
    line2[i] = d;
    // or, if you want to keep it on one line:
    // line2[i] = lookup[line2[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By making 26 separate substitutions, the later ones are stepping on the results of the earlier ones. You need to find a way to make each substitution occur only once per character.

Comment: A tip for doing it once per character is having _two_ strings, a source and a destination, and convert from one to the other.

Comment: i'm trying to use replace_copy but when i cout v it is empty as if it isn't copying to line3

`for (int i=0;i<26;i++) {
replace_copy(line2.begin(), line2.end(),line3.begin(), key[i], fox[i]);
}
v.push_back( line3 );`

Answer (score -1):

In C++ you can access and modify string elements with square brackets. For example:

```
String str("dog");
str[1] = 'c';
//str = "dcg"
```

So you can use this notation instead of `replace()`. If replacing doesn't work as you intend it to then maybe your key is wrong.

Comment: This is true, but it's not the problem here.  replace is effectively just wrapping up multiple assignments.